# fillRect() Causes my script to fail

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm new to HTML 5 animations using a canvas, and I was just wondering what is wrong with this code. I am using the latest version of Google Chrome. Thanks in advance.

Note that this is the first time I ever use JavaScript and HTML5 for game making so any tips are appreciated.

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
canvas.width = 1000;
canvas.height = 600;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var player = {
    speed: 256,
    x: canvas.width/2,
    y: canvas.height/2,
};



var keysDown = {};
var move;

addEventListener("keydown",function (e) {keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;}, false);
addEventListener("keyup",function (e) {delete keysDown[e.keyDown];},false);

var update = function(modifier) {
    move = player.speed*modifier;
    if (38 in keysDown) player.y -= move;
    if (40 in keysDown) player.y += move;
    if (37 in keysDown) player.x -= move;
    if (39 in keysDown) player.x += move;
};

var render = function () {
    ctx.fillRect(player.x,player.y,20,20);
};

var main = function(){
    var now = Date.now();
    var delta = now - then;

    update(delta / 1000);
    then = now;
};

var then = Date.now();
setInterval(main,16);
```

**Edit:**
Changed

```
player = {
    speed: 256,
    x: canvas.width/2
    y: canvas.height/2
};
```

and added commas.

**Edit:**
Changed `setInterval(main,1)` to `setInterval(main,16)`.

**EDIT:**
Found the error yet I'm not sure why it's an error.

In another one of my canvas experiments in which I used images instead of `fillRect()`, I changed all the rendering of the images to `fillRect` and the script didn't work.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: I would look into d3 in the future. It's the best javascript graphics engine (imo).

Comment: *"I was just wondering what is wrong with this code"* That's what *you* should tell *us*. What do you expect it to do and what does it do instead? Are there any error messages in the javascript error console of your browser?

Comment: It's supposed to show a rectangle that moves whenever you press one of the arrow keys, and instead, it just shows a blank screen. I'm not really sure how to check the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

```
var player = {
    speed: 256,
    x: canvas.width/2,
    y: canvas.height/2
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are basically blocking the browser by using an interval of 1 ms.

Try with something more realistic:

```
setInterval(main, 16);
```

Or consider using `requestAnimationFrame` instead (recommended).

Comment: OK. I changed that but I still see nothing in the browser.

Comment: @user2921024 please provide a fiddle so we can dig into this a bit deeper as it's a bit unclear what really goes on (perhaps in other parts of the code)

Comment: The code is supposed to make a box that moves around when the arrow keys are pressed. A for the other parts of the code, this is the **only** piece of code that I have apart from the HTML.